# VBA : Copying the specific columns from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi  i am trying to copy the specific columns from one sheet to another sheet but the below code getting run time error 1004' object defined or application defined error on `.Range(MyCopyRange).Copy` this code. anybody can assist it would appreciate.

```
Sub CopyingColms()
Dim LR As Long, MyCopyRange As Variant, MyPasteRange As Variant, X As Long
ThisWorkbook.Activate
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MyCopyRange = Array("C2:C" & LR, "E2:E" & LR, "B2:B" & LR, "F2:F" & LR, "G2:G" & LR, "H2:H" & LR, "I2:I" & LR, "K2:K" & LR, "J2:J" & LR, "L2:L" & LR, "M2:M" & LR, "N:2:N" & LR, "AE2:AE" & LR, "Z2:Z" & LR, "D2:D" & LR, "AG2:AG" & LR, "AF2:AF" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
    MyPasteRange = Array("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2")

    If LR > 1 Then
        For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
            .Range(MyCopyRange).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(MyPasteRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Next
    Else
        Range("A2") = "No Data Found for this month"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just needed a loop to pull out array elements.

Please try the below code.

```
Sub CopyingColms()
Dim LR As Long, X As Long
ThisWorkbook.Activate
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MyCopyRange = Array("C2:C" & LR, "E2:E" & LR, "B2:B" & LR, "F2:F" & LR, "G2:G" & LR, "H2:H" & LR, "I2:I" & LR, "K2:K" & LR, "J2:J" & LR, "L2:L" & LR, "M2:M" & LR, "N:2:N" & LR, "AE2:AE" & LR, "Z2:Z" & LR, "D2:D" & LR, "AG2:AG" & LR, "AF2:AF" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
    MyPasteRange = Array("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2")

    If LR > 1 Then
    j = 1 'added
        For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
       .Range(MyCopyRange(j)).COPY
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(MyPasteRange(j)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1 'added
        Next
    Else
        Range("A2") = "No Data Found for this month"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```