# Extract a particular column from another workbook and copy to the destination workbook

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have two workbooks, source workbook and a Destination workbook.

I would like to copy particular column (A,C;D;E;F;G;K;AP;AV;AW;AX)containing data from source workbook to the Destination workbook in column (A till E).  I already searched through the page and could find a code like below

```
Sub Extract()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Value As Variant


Set y = ThisWorkbook 
Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\data\Jenny_Work.xlsx")

Value = x.Sheets("Work_Jenny").Range("A1").Value
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Value

x.Close

End Sub
```

It would be great if you can suggest me for the above criteria
Thanking in advance

Comment: Whats your criteria to copy 11 columns into 5 columns?

Comment: specify correct columns to copy & paste

Comment: @Mrig sorry mrig,  I want to copy from A till K, in sequence. That was an typo error.

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan how do you mean ? I dint understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

it is working for me!

```
 Sub Extract()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Value As Variant


Set y = ThisWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("G:\Book1.xlsm")

lRow = x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dRow = y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Union(y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & dRow), y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & dRow)).Copy
x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Application.CutCopyMode = False

x.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: The code works. But the criteria for me is to paste only selected columns.

Comment: This deleted first two columns and pasted the other columns

Comment: for me, I Need only the columns i mentioned in the post.

Comment: Ya, Thank you. Could u comment in the side, what  you are doing. it would be easy for me to understand

Comment: it will paste only selected columns only. for example i give column ("A","B") like wise you have to add your columns (A,C;D;E;F;G;K;AP;AV;AW;AX)in my code line number 13

Comment: sorry, there is a small Problem with my original sheet. I have few Buttons in my sheet and data starts from row 4. How do i Change the range to row 4 ? sorry, just realized when working with original sheet

Comment: I changed the range to A5 in the Destination sheet. but it has an application defined error

Comment: I tried using like Range("A5:K1000") like this, still i  get an error. Could you Please help to solve this? would be greatful

Comment: you mean like , for i = 5 to lastrow, Cells(i, 1).value ?

Comment: y.Worksheets("Red").Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll i tried this and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a sheet is not the same as a workbook as this will create confusion. 
A workbook/excel file can contain multiple sheets/worksheets and not the other way around.

That being said here is your code:

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

Sheets("Master").Select
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(1, lCol))
    Union(Range("A1:A" & lRow), Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\YourMap\" & cell.Value & ".xls" 'You might want to change the extension (.xls) according to your excel version
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Just watch the file extension within the code (look for green text after pasting.).

Comment: ya, I will try and tell you

Comment: Hi Jenny, pls review https://stackoverflow.com/q/45032075/7676648.This code also requires to copy selected columns to be copied and pasted

Comment: @Deepak Ahirwar, I am getting Application defined error in the line source column =

Comment: @ApurvPawar they are between Sheets, and i Need between workbooks

Comment: @ApurvPawar i could understand the code better, but i dont know how to Frame them between workbooks. could yu help me by posting an code for workbooks?

Comment: Do you use Team Viewer?

Comment: @DeepakAhirwar no i dont use Team viewer

Comment: @DeepakAhirwar i still get an application defined error

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of it. So that i can read the error. OR whole code

Comment: Ya, @DeepakAhirwar

Comment: @DeepakAhirwar it working in the reverse way, i want the code in Destination sheet, but this copied the data from Destination to source sheet .

Comment: @DeepakAhirwar i did a mistake with Sheets. sorry :(

Comment: What was that?What was that?